# How can I search for Gmail messages on a particular date?

Tags: gmail, search, date

I'm searching for a message on or about a particular date and rather than scrolling through my emails to go back about a year, I'd like to know a search method to only find emails from a particular date or date range. How can I do this with Gmail?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use the `before` and `after` keywords in your search, for example:

```
after:2012/4/26 before:2012/5/3
```

To search for emails between April 26, 2012 and May 3, 2012.

Answer (score 29):

1. In the right hand side of the gmail search bar there is a drop-down arrow- click it.
   [image: gmail search]
2. The drop-down includes a date range option, and you should be all set from there
   [image: gmail search date]

Answer (score 3):

For emails on a particular date (e.g. on 12 July 2017) enter this in search box:

> after:2017/7/12 before:2017/7/13

Answer (score 2):

I put together a redirect for searching just 'back n days' that does the simple (and for me, most common use case)

Writing a search for ‘inbox NOT including today’ is slightly counterintuitive and somewhat of a pain so I put together a custom redirect of my own that brings up the stuff from yesterday:

http://joereddington.com/back/0

That redirects you to your inbox with a custom search string, showing only those emails that turned up before today. It’s parameterisable so

http://joereddington.com/back/4

takes you back four days and

http://joereddington.com/back/10

takes you back ten days

Code, screenshots, and reasoning are all at http://joereddington.com/4008/2014/08/04/gmail-for-yesterdays-jobs/